# Update Text in ASP.NET text box

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, admin, edit

I'm trying to update text in an SQL database using a text box. This is for an admin to overwrite the data in the database. Having trouble declaring one of the variables. 
The itemnametext doesn't exist in the current context.

Code for itemediting page:

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="admin_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>elmtree - Admin</title>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/mylist.css" />

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <img src="images/ELleft.png" style="width:226px; height:52px; margin-top: 3px; margin-left: 17px; text-align: justify; float: none;"/></a></li>



<div class="container">
    <h1> Item Edit </h1> </div>

        <div class="container">

            <div class="form-group">

                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Item name: </label> 

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="itemnameedit" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="form-control">

                    </asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <asp:Button CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ID="updatebutton" role="button" runat="server" Text="save" OnClick="updatebutton_Click" />
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Code for itemediting.aspx.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Configuration;



public partial class admin_itemediting : System.Web.UI.Page{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int row = 0;
        if (Request.QueryString["itemID"] != null){

            row = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["itemID"]);
        }
        else{
            Response.Redirect("itemedit.aspx");
        }




        string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
            ["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);


        myConnection.Open();


        string query = "SELECT * FROM reports WHERE ID=@rowid";


        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);

        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rowid", row);


        SqlDataReader rdr = myCommand.ExecuteReader();


        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            string myname = rdr["itemname"].ToString();

            itemnametext.Text = myname;
        }
    }
    protected void updatebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

        string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings ["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        myConnection.Open();

    string itemnametextupdate = itemnametext.Text;

    string query = "UPDATE reports SET itemname = @itemnewname";

    }













    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change ID of your texbox from `itemnameedit` to `itemnametext`
Update: change your reference here to match the codefile and **codefile class**. I dont think you have right reference, so **codefile class** `admin_itemediting` don't know any of your control in the aspx file.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="itemediting.aspx.cs" Inherits="admin_itemediting" %>
```

Comment: I have already tried doing this and it does not work. It is telling me 'itemnametext' does not exist in the current context..

Answer (score 0):

Your textbox name is itemnameedit so itemnametext is not found

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="itemnametext" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```

**EDIT**: Your aspx page is Default and you are posting code for itemediting.aspx.cs.Post the code for itemediting.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="admin_Default" %>
```

Comment: I have already tried doing this and it does not work. It is telling me 'itemnametext' does not exist in the current context..